# cp in multi line fashion

Tags: cp

In CentOS with Bash 3.2.52(2) I have to copy many files (not all) from one directory to another.

I can create a long one liner such as `cp /"$HOME"/dir1/{file1,fil2} ... /"$HOME"/dir2` but because there are many files in dir1 I prefer to copy files in a multi line fashion.
EDIT: I create the list manually.

How can this be done?
<sub>I would prefer a no backslashes solution | I didn't find a clue in `man cp` | maybe only heredocument?</sub>

Comment: Do you want copy all files in `dir1` directory or some?

Comment: Just some in a multi line list I will make inside the script.

Comment: Why would you not want backslashes? Do the name of the files that you'd want to copy follow some pattern, or do the names of the files that you _don't_ want to copy follow some pattern?

Comment: Repetitive usage of backslashes is something I personally feel bad with. None of the files necessarily follow any specific pattern; some might have extensions, some not, some would be named only by numbers, some only by letters, or a mix, some with or without special characters and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
files=(
    file1 file2 "the goose incident.png"
    "another file"
    file3 file-4 "fifth file" file6
    "this is file7 with a
newline in the middle of the name" )

cd ~/dir1 &&
cp "${files[@]}" ~/dir2
```

This would copy the names mentioned in the `files` list from `~/dir1` to `~/dir2`.

The newlines between the elements in the `files` list are not important, except for the newline in the last element which is a filename with a newline embedded in it (just to show that you can have these as well, without issues).

The list could also have been written

```
files=(
    file1
    file2
    "the goose incident.png"
    "another file"
    file3
    file-4
    "fifth file"
    file6
    "this is file7 with a
newline in the middle of the name"
)
```

or as

```
files=( file1 file2 "the goose incident.png" "another file" file3 file-4
        "fifth file" file6 "this is file7 with a
newline in the middle of the name" )
```

Comment: Thanks; please share why you chose to not separate some of the files to different lines (as with `file1` and `file2`) and why are there strings inside? In appreciation,

Comment: @JohnDoea See update. Each string in the `files` list is a filename that you want to copy. Since you never said anything about what your filenames were, I had to invent my own, so I tried to cover all cases including single-word filenames, filenames with spaces, and filenames with newlines embedded in them.

Comment: With `seq 1 1000000` files in the list it fails with `/usr/bin/cp: Argument list too long`. OP said that he needs to copy *many* files but didn't specify an exact number so I think he should be aware of that

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It does, but if the files don't follow a fixed pattern (not even a common filename prefix or suffix), it is less likely that the number of files is that great.  As soon as either the files to include or the files to exclude follows any form of pattern (such as a numeric interval, a prefix/suffix or some other pattern), the names would no longer have to be stored in a list at all, as it becomes a simple matter of testing the names against a set of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files="1
2
3
4
4
5
6
7
8
9 10 11"

IFS=$'\n'
for file in $files
do
    touch "$file"
done
```

Just replace `touch "$file"` with what you need.  The
disadvantage of this solution is that it will fork a new process for
each file as you can see with `strace` and thus will be slow for a
large number of files:

```
$ strace -f ./cp-here-doc.sh  |& grep 'execve("/usr/bin/touch"'
[pid 17917] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "1"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17918] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "2"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17919] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "3"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17920] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "4"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17921] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "4"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17922] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "5"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17923] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "6"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17924] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "7"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17925] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "8"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 17926] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "9 10 11"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
```

You can use `xargs` to run `touch`, or `cp` in your final script only
once and make script run faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files="1
2
3
4
4
5
6
7
8
9 10 11"

echo "$files" | tr '\n' '\0'  | xargs -0 touch
```

Result:

```
$ strace -f ./cp-here-doc.sh  |& grep 'execve("/usr/bin/touch"'
[pid 18290] execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9 10 11"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
```

Also notice that on Linux at least filenames can contain newlines so
you have to pick another delimiter if at least one of your filenames
contains a newline.

OP asked:

> what does IFS=$'\n' mean

It means a literal new line.  You can read about it `man bash`:

```
   Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word
   expands to string, with backslash-escaped char- acters replaced
   as specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape
   sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
          \a     alert (bell)
          \b     backspace
          \e
          \E     an escape character
          \f     form feed
          \n     new line
```

Your final script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files="1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9 10 11"

echo "$files" | tr '\n' '\0'  | xargs -0 cp -t {} dir
```

I'd really go with `xargs` option as it is *much* faster and safer - see Kusalananda's comment below. I didn't run
tests with `cp` command but when I tested `touch` to create files in
the `$(seq 1 1000000)` list it took only 16 seconds for `xargs` to do
this but it took a whooping 42 minutes for the for loop version. Also,
to my surprise `xargs` was able to split argument list into several
commands so that `Argument list too long` will not be an issue.

Comment: Hi and thanks; please tell me, what does `IFS=$'\n'` mean? Also, shouldn't `touch` create empty files instead of replicating the "copied" files? Thank you,

Comment: See updated answer. Yes, `touch` is just an example as I said. We don't know what is your destination directory and what options you want to use with `cp`.

Comment: Unless you also use `set -f`, the shell will additionally perform filename globbing on each of the split-up words.

Comment: @Kusalananda: ok, thanks, I forgot about that. I've updated my answer.