# Just one file echoed from an array of files

Tags: bash, ksh, cp, array

I try to copy 2 or more files from one directory to another with `cp` using an array.
I executed:

```
files=(
    LocalSettings.php
    robots.txt
    .htaccess
    ${domain}.png
    googlec69e044fede13fdc.htm
)
```

<sub>filenames indented with tabulations;</sub>

I aim to execute afterwards:

```
cp -a "source_path/${files[@]}" "/destanation_path"
```

my problem is that while testing the variable itself,
`echo $files` returned only the first filename `LocalSettings.php` and not the full list of files.
How would you explain this?

<sub>Related: [cp in multi line fashion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536017/cp-in-multi-line-fashion);</sub>

Comment: Note how I, [in my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536029/116858) to the related question, use `cd` to change to the source directory before copying. If I didn't do that, I would have to specify the full path to the files in the list, e.g. `source_path/LocalSottings.php source_path/robots.txt` etc.  Also `$files` would always be the same as `${files[0]}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `Bash` feature described in `man bash`:

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to
>   referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

If you want to print all members of `files` array:

```
echo "${files[@]}"
```

Also described in `man bash`:

> ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word.

Answer (score 3):

`$files` and `${files[0]}` is equivalent when `files` is a list such as the one you have in your question.

Note that `"source_path/${files[@]}"` only puts `source_path/` before the first element of the list.
To modify the list in such a way that each element is prefixed by some path, you can do

```bash
files=( ... your list of files ... )

for element in "${files[@]}"; do
    files=( "${files[@]:1}" "source_path/$element" )
done

cp "${files[@]}" destanation_path
```

or, you could just `cd` to `source_path` before doing the `cp`, or add the path to the actual names at the same time as you assign the values in the list from the start.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, `$files` only expands to the first element of the array, and `"source_path/${files[@]}"` only attaches "source_path/" to the first element. But there's a relatively simple way to get all elements, with a path prepended to each:

```
cp -a "${files[@]/#/source_path/}" "/destanation_path"
```

This combines the all-elements expansion (`[@]`) with a substitution. `/#` means "replace at beginning of string", then the empty string to replace, then `/` to delimit the replacement, then "source_path/" as the thing to replace (/add). This attaches the source path to each element, and doesn't get confused by funny characters in the elements like some versions do.

Note that in the above example, "source_path/" has a slash at the end but not the beginning; the "/" right before it is a delimiter. If it started with a slash and contained more slashes, like "/source/path/", it'd still work:

```
cp -a "${files[@]/#//source/path/}" "/destanation_path"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try the following snippet:

```
IFS=$'\n'
cp -a $( printf "source_path/%s\n" "${files[@]}" ) /destination_path/
```

It should also work with filenames with spaces.

Comment: It works with file names containing spaces, but not with file names containing newlines or wildcards. It's also completely pointless, since `cp -a "${files[@]}" /destination_path/` works strictly better.

Comment: @Gilles, it's not completely pointless, the `printf` adds the `source_path/` prefix which wasn't there in the array entries.