# Why does xargs work with some commands but not others?

Tags: xargs

I can run this command and it works:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs md5sum
```

This prints the md5sum for each file.

But for other commands it seems to pass all the files to a single invocation of the command.  For instance, both `printf` and `echo` seem to have this problem. With `printf` I get this warning:

```
printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with ...
```

While with echo it only prints one line, for instance if I have this command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 echo GOT
```

I only see "GOT" printed once, on the same line as all files found.

I thought maybe it was because echo is also a builtin, but I get the same behavior if I explicitly run /bin/echo.

For reference, I even have this issue in manufactured commands:

```
$ echo "a b c" | xargs echo GOT
GOT a b c
```

instead of:

```
GOT a
GOT b
GOT c
```

What am I doing wrong?  It's helpful for me to debug my commands first by prefixing them with `echo` and I'm not even able to do that.

Edit: As mentioned in a comment, I can't actually use the `-exec` option to `find` and in actuality my pipeline is a bit longer with a sort included, but this seemed like an extraneous detail not relevant to the fact that I can't get the simpler pipeline to work even.

Comment: you ask what you're doing wrong, and i would suggest the answer is "piping find to xargs". there's a `-exec` option for a reason

Comment: @Fox Which is why I am baffled as to why `find` doesn't have a way to sort the output... instead I have to pipe it to sort, after which I can no longer pass it to `-exec`!

Comment: sounds to me like you are suffering from trying to cram several lines of logic into one line to save time, then wasting tons of time wondering why it doesn't work, lol. Why not just use more lines of code, which will always work, for everything, always, without exception? One liners are like a temptress, seems so simple, until you start to realize you are not saving time or effort, quite the opposite. The more time I spend with this stuff, the less likely I am to use them for complicated solutions, like getting results, sorting them, then acting on that sort.

Comment: "But for other commands it seems to pass all the files to a single invocation of the command." ... Uh, that's what happens with `md5sum` too.

Comment: Try `echo "a b c" | xargs -n 1 echo GOT`

Comment: @muru Oh.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `xargs command-arg` as a command that runs a single
instance of `command-arg` with everything it got from a standard input
delimited by some delimiter (whitespace by default or NUL byte as you
use in your examples) appended to it. For example:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs something
```

would run `something 1 2 3`. Or using the example you posted in your
question:

```
echo "a b c" | xargs echo GOT
```

runs `echo GOT a b c`.

If you want to fork a new instance of command-arg with every single
argument xargs got from standard input you can use -n1 option:

```
$ echo "a b c" | xargs -n1 echo GOT
GOT a
GOT b
GOT c
```

Of course note that some commands do not accept multiple arguments and
therefore have to be always run with `-n1`.

The advantage of using xargs is that spawning a new process is an
expensive operation so it's faster to run a single process with
multiple arguments, check some benchmarks I did in this answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536023/72304

Comment: `xargs` might run the command multiple times, if there's lots of input entries. GNU xargs has `--show-limits` to tell what the limit is set to. Of course it usually doesn't matter for commands that treat all the given files identically.

Comment: It can also be a disaster. One of my less able clients had (for several years) been using `xargs tar czf ../Backup.tgz`, and was very pleased with the compression he achieved. It was creating about five .tgz files each time, only the last surviving. He had never tested his recovery strategy either. And he blamed me for being unable to recover files that no longer existed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "use `-n1`" mentioned in the first answer, your shell may have built-in versions of some commands. If a command is invoked from a different program (e.g., from `xargs`), it will invoke an external program instead of the shell's built-in version.

In particular, `printf` is built into Bash and several other shells, and Bash's built-in version will repeat the format as many times as necessary to use up all the arguments.

For example, using Bash's built-in version,

```
printf '%s and %s\n' How now brown cow
```

will output 2 lines, whereas

```
/usr/bin/printf '%s and %s\n' How now brown cow
```

may complain that it has too many arguments, depending on the version you have installed.

Comment: `printf` from GNU coreutils does not complain about extra args; it works the same way as Bash's built-in version.

Comment: the coreutils printf does complain already with coreutils 8.4 (from around 2013): `/usr/bin/printf foo bar doo` prints `foo` and the error `/usr/bin/printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with ‘bar’`. Of course it doesn't complain if there's a format string that can eat the args, I think it's defined to repeat it.

Comment: Also, you know you can just edit your earlier answer, no need to write a new one?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule I would avoid `xargs`.

Most of the examples you'll find on the web are fragile - they will break in unexpected ways if the environment doesn't match the assumptions of the person who wrote the code.

Even the example given in this question has a bug: it uses `find`...`-print0` but then uses `xargs` *without* `-0`.

Moreover, most uses of `xargs` are unnecessary. In particular, when it's used in combination with `find`, it's both more reliable and less error-prone to use an `-exec` expression within `find`.

The example given can be replaced by:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +
```

Comment: Thought about voting this answer down, but after all it's your personal rule and one may disagree or agree.

Comment: I agree that if you don't understand xargs, you should avoid using it.  I don't agree that xargs should generally be avoided.  Perhaps it is best to say it should be used only when it is appropriate.  :)

Comment: That's a fair comment. However I find that it's "appropriate" only about 1% as often as it typically gets used; hence I start with "as a rule" - because there are always exceptions.